# Trigger AWS Lambda on launch of RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to trigger AWS Lambda as soon as RDS Instance is launch, same I am able to achieve with EC2 as we have Cloud Watch Event Pattern availabe but for RDS, no event pattern seems to be working, Can anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out, remove requestParameters from end.

```
{
    "source": [
        "aws.rds"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
        "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "eventSource": [
            "rds.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "eventName": [
            "CreateDBInstance"
        ],
        "requestParameters": {
            "dBInstanceIdentifier": [
                "database"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```